# How to replace empty numpy array by grayscale image values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

EDIT: I have found a workaround, which is assigning it to an array, then use that array to create a numpy array:
a = []

```
for i in range(0,width/image_size):
    for j in range(0,height/image_size):
        roi = img[image_size*j:image_size*(j+1),image_size*i:image_size*(i+1)]
        a.append(roi)

arr = np.asarray(a) #HERE
```

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I have created an empty numpy array of shape (180,28,28), which should hold 180 gray scale images size 28x28.

```
height, width = img.shape[:2]    
arr = np.empty(((height/image_size)*(width/image_size), 28, 28 )) #arr.shape = (180,28,28)
```

I have multiple image regions size 28x28 that I want to populate into `arr`

```
for i in range(0,width/image_size):
    for j in range(0,height/image_size):
        roi = img[image_size*j:image_size*(j+1),image_size*i:image_size*(i+1)]
        #HERE - how can I set the value in arr to be an (28x28) roi
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you've found the solution please post it as an answer.

Comment: @lukess Apologies. At first, I edited the question by adding my answer, but now I have posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround, which is assigning it to an array, then use that array to create a numpy array:

```
a = []

for i in range(0,width/image_size):
    for j in range(0,height/image_size):
        roi = img[image_size*j:image_size*(j+1),image_size*i:image_size*(i+1)]
        a.append(roi)

arr = np.asarray(a)  #assign it to numpy array here
```

However, I'm not sure if there is a better, or more elegant way to do it.